# How do I play a notification sound with max volume even in background?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

I need to play a sound in Android, when a notification is received, even in background. This is like Uber Driver or other apps: they play sounds at max volume even if the phone is muted and the app is in background.

I tried this without luck:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Check Code

> notificationBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));